# How to calculate output voltage for an Analogue to Digital converter

Tags: adc

A 3 1/2 digit, 2V full-scale slope ADC has its integration time set to 300ms.If the input to ADC is (1 + sin 314t), then what will be the ADC output.

As far I know, Vout = Vin/Vref * 2^n

> Here n=3 or 3.5?
>   Also Vin = magnitude of 1+ sin 314t =?

Comment: 3 1/2 *decimal* digits would mean a range from 0 to 5000. A 12-bit ADC can detect 2^12 = 4096 unique values, so I guess close enough? (1 + sin 314t) is just a 50 Hz 1 V pk-pk sine with a 1 v DC offset, but in order to calculate the actual value at any given time we need the value of t. Expressing ADC precision in decimal digits is weird, why would anybody want to do that?

Comment: 3 and 1/2 digit ADC is an ADC which can measure up to 1999.

Comment: So it's an arbitrary measure of how large a number can be displayed on a seven segment display, as in a digital multimeter.

Comment: The ADC output voltage is digital and unimportant.

Comment: @jms: There's a long tradition of specifying DMM resolution in exactly this way. Where have you been for the last 30 years?

Answer (score 2):

Two hints:

- The output of the ADC is \$\frac{Vin}{Vref}\cdot \text{max count}\$, and in a binary converter, max count is indeed 2<sup>n</sup>. However, in this case, you already know that max count is 1999, so that's what you use.
- A dual-slope converter is an integrator, so it measures the mean (average) of the input voltage over the duration of the integrating interval. What can you say about the mean of a sinewave?

Comment: Thanks for the help.   As I see it, the average value of a sine wave is 0.637 * Peak value.   So, is the > Vin=1+(0.637*1)=1.637 ?

Comment: That might be the average value of a half-cycle, but what is the average over 300 ms?